# ListItem.onItemClickListener with CustomAdapter unresponsive

Tags: java, listview, android-sqlite, simplecursoradapter

I have a custom list_item, and the listview it's in has an `onItemClickListener` that goes to a new Activity. The problem I'm facing is that the `onItemClickListener` is unresponsive due to it not being able to recognize the `ID` of the item clicked. I suspect this problem is originating from my `CustomAdapter` but I'm unsure as to what can be done to fix it. The logged ID is listed as:

> D/ListDataActivity: onItemClick: You Clicked on android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@22fda4b

ListDataActivity.java:

```
public class ListDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "ListDataActivity";

DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
TextView mTaskName;
TextView mTaskDesc;
ArrayAdapter adapter;
CustomAdapter customAdapter;
private ListView mListView;
DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    mTaskDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.task_desc);
    mTaskName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.task_name);

    populateListView();
}
private void populateListView() {
    String[] fromColumns = mDatabaseHelper.databaseToStringArray();
    int[] toViews = new int[]{R.id.task_name, R.id.task_desc};
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + mDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE 1 ", null);
    Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in the ListView.");
    SimpleCursorAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, fromColumns, toViews,0);
    mListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);



    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on " + name);
            Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getItemID(name);
            int priority = 10;
            int itemID = -1;
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                itemID = data.getInt(0);
            }
            if(itemID > -1){
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: The ID is: " + itemID);
                Intent editScreenIntent = new Intent(ListDataActivity.this, EditDataActivity.class);
                editScreenIntent.putExtra("id",itemID);
                editScreenIntent.putExtra("name",name);
                editScreenIntent.putExtra("priority",priority);
                startActivity(editScreenIntent);
            }
            else{
                toastMessage("No ID associated with that name");
            }
        }
    });
}
private void toastMessage(String message){
    Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

CustomAdapter.java:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private int layout;
private Context context;
private DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    this.layout = layout;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    Cursor c = getCursor();

    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    bindView(v, context, c);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {

    int taskNameColumn = c.getColumnIndex(mDatabaseHelper.COL2);
    int taskDescColumn = c.getColumnIndex(mDatabaseHelper.COL4);

    String mTaskName = c.getString(taskNameColumn);
    String mTaskDesc = c.getString(taskDescColumn);

    TextView taskName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.task_name);
    if (taskName != null){
        taskName.setText(mTaskName);
    }
    TextView taskDesc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.task_desc);
    if (taskDesc != null){
        taskDesc.setText(mTaskDesc);
    }
}
```

}

And here is my list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/task_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/viewbutton"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:background="@layout/round" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/task_desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/task_name"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="Undefined"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

If you would like me to elaborate on any of this I would be happy to. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using a CursorAdapter then **l** (the 4th parameter passed to the overidden **onItemClick** method) will be the **id**. This assumes that the **_id** column is an alias of the **rowid** (i.e. you have `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` coded with or without `AUTOINCREMENT`).

- ***NOTE*** the 4th parameter **'l'**, for other adapters (e.g. ArrayAdapter) will not be the **id** rather it is typically the position (as a long) and thus the same as the the third parameter.

As such try `Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on " + name + " with an id of " + String.valueOf(l));`

name is showing as `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@22fda4b` because the underyling item, which is retrieved by **getItem** is the Cursor who's **toString** method will be the default inherited method that prints the reference to the object.

You probably want something like :-

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Intent editScreenIntent = new Intent(ListDataActivity.this, EditDataActivity.class);
        editScreenIntent.putExtra("id",l); //<<<<<<<<<< THE ID AS kindly supplied by the CursorAdapter
        editScreenIntent.putExtra("name",data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(mDatabaseHelper.COL2)));
        editScreenIntent.putExtra("priority",data.getColumnIndex(mDatabaseHelper.COL4));
        startActivity(editScreenIntent);
        }
    }
});
```

- However, you could easily (and arguably more correctly) just pass the id via the intent and then retrieve the data (name and priority) from the table in the invoked activity.
- Note the above code is in-principle code, it has not been tested so may contain errors.
- The Cursor should be positioned at the current row/respective row so need need to do any moves.